# Importing my package from a Django management command

Tags: python, django, setuptools, django-management-command

I've written a package which was originally a command-line tool, but I've decided that for Django it should be run from a management command. I've installed my external package (called `codequal`) using `pip install --editable`, and I can successfully use `manage.py shell` to import a module from that package:

```
in[0]: from codequal import something
in[1]: something.some_method()
out[2]: u'result'
```

This works fine. However, when I try to do the same thing in a management command, I run into an error:

```
File "/home/path/to/django/project/some_app/management/commands/codequal.py", line 8, in <module>
    from codequal import something
ImportError: cannot import name something
```

Why is this? I can use other installed packages from management commands. Could it be something to do with my setup.py? I can post snippets from that if needed. Mainly I'm wondering if this part is to blame:

```
    entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'codequal = codequal.cli:main',
    ],
```

Does this prevent from the module being imported from certain places? I can't see how it would, since I can do it from `manage.py shell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your file (codequal.py) has the same name that the module. You need to change one of them. I recomended the file inside the app:

```
/home/path/to/django/project/some_app/management/commands/codequal.py
```

to

```
/home/path/to/django/project/some_app/management/commands/codequal_utils.py
```